# Error Rails on Fedora 22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fedora

When I want to create an application using `rails new firstapp` I get an error saying it requires the gem "byebug".

When I tried to install it using `gem install byebug` I got another error saying the necessary headers are missing.

Please tell me how to fix it.

[Screen of my mistakes](http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2015-06/18/8mhox1pos96j.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use a screenshot to show us information necessary to help you. Images get compressed and reduced in size making them very difficult to read. Also, we can't easily copy/paste the information for reuse when searching or replying. In addition, please don't use links to images for data that is critical. *WHEN* the link breaks the question becomes unintelligible and useless to anyone else searching for the solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install Fedora Development Tools

```
su -
yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
```

and/or ruby develop

```
yum -y install gcc ruby-devel rubygems
```